# I want to be able to change activies either automatically or by pressing button. This code works, but it bugs out after pressing a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How could I fix this? It works but it bugs out. I don't know what to try any more. I want activity to change either by button press or automatically. And if button isn't pressed to continue on the next activity- not to skip some of them.

```
public class Ljeto extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ljeto);
```

This is the start, i have defined intent and buttons.

```
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.NaprijedLjeto);
        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.NazadLjeto);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Proljece.class);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Here i started the actions which work perfect. All up until timer.

```
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });

       button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              startActivity(intent1);
           }
       });

       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               startActivity(intent2);
           }
       }, 5000);
   }
}
```

This work is for my school. I have tried everything I know but it just doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: `It works but it bugs out.` what does that mean ? what's working, what isn't ?

Comment: The app bugs out. It just starts wilding. No schedule, no changing after a period. Buttons work but again, After the Winter photo, there isn't autumn photo but summer for example.

Answer (score 0):

*Use this code

```
 new  Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        startActivity(intent2);

    },5000);
```

instead of

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {




            startActivity(intent2);



        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: When i use this code, my buttons don't work at all, neither do the activities switch.